# Closed form of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^\frac{1}{n}}{n^s} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I was evaluating an integral a while ago that appeared in a Youtube video, which I expressed in terms of the Riemann-zeta function (which seems to emerge from the argument of such sums, rather frequently - although this appearance of $\zeta(s)$ was alluded to by the thumbnail). However, my attention was soon centred on $\zeta(s)$ itself and the idea of plugging $x^\frac{1}{n}$ in the numerator each of the terms came to mind (the $s$ in the modified $\zeta(s)$ could be then be viewed as a parameter).

The sum would then look like this: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^\frac{1}{n}}{n^s}.$$ This is similar to the polylogarithm, $Li_s(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^s}$, except  $\frac{1}{n}$ appears in the exponent of $x$ instead of $n$.

My question would then be: Does a closed form exist for such a sum? If so, what would it look like? I'm particularly interested in the closed form of this sum for $s=2$, which would look like this: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^\frac{1}{n}}{n^2}$$

If you know the answer to this question, please could you tell me? It would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance! (p.s. by closed form I really mean in terms of known functions that can be expressed together in a finite number of operations to construct the equivalent of this series, like log(x), sin(x), cos(x), or even things like $\Gamma(x)$,  erf(x) etc.; it would be fascinating to see if the values of this function are algebraically independent of other rational, irrational, or transcendental constants - or if this is an entirely different function on its own, but I'm getting ahead of myself).

Comment: I doubt it has a closed form.

Comment: Note that even the Polylogarithm function you mention does not have a "closed form". Usually in analysis when a function is used "often" some notation is invented for that function and then used. A very pedantic person might say that even the natural logarithm, trig functions and square roots do not have a "closed form" expression, because they cannot be calculated in a finite number of steps.

What do you mean with "closed form"?

Comment: Maybe [this integral representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+representation+x%5E%281%2Fn%29) of $(1+z)^a$ helps? Then interchange the sum and integral if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the series of $e^x$, you get a zeta series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt[n]x}{n^s}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\zeta(n+s)\ln^n(x)}{n!}\iff \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\zeta(n+s)x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^\frac xn}{n^s} $$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%281%2F2%29%5E%281%2Fn%29%2Fn%5E2%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfty%7D%5D%2Csum%5Bzeta%28m%2B2%29+%28ln%281%2F2%29%29%5Em%2Fm%21%2C%7Bm%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%5D)

Using $\zeta(s)=\frac1{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t-1} dt$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt[n]x}{n^s}=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{s-1}} {e^t-1}\,_0 \tilde{\text F}_1(s,t\ln(x))dt$$

[Shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B+eulergamma%5E%281%2Fn%29%2Fn%5Ekhinchin%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfty%7D%5D%2Cintegral%5Bt%5E%28khinchin-1%29%2F%28e%5Et-1%29+hypergeometric0F1regularized%28khinchin%2Ct+ln%28eulergamma%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C20%7D%5D) where the [regularized confluent hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric0F1Regularized/) appears.

Comment: Also $\int_0^\infty y^{z-1}\sum_{n\ge 1} e^{-y/n} n^{-s}dy  = \Gamma(z)\zeta(s-z)$